# Cannot load mod_rewrite Apache module

Tags: php, apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I am trying to use `mod_rewrite` module of `Apache24 server`, but I am not being able to load it. I know there have been many questions asked regarding this topic and I have gone through all of them but nothing seem to work. These are the steps that I have followed until now---

1. CHANGED `httpd.conf` file made these changes:
   a. Uncommented `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`
   b. Changed `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`
2. Restarted apache server
3. Checked loaded modules using command prompt command `httpd -M`. I can see there that the mod_rewrite module has loaded. I am attaching the image below.

[image: The screen shot of my command prompt]

But after performing all these steps I can't see mod_rewrite as loaded module in `phpinfo`.

[image: Screenshot of phpinfo file]

As it can be seen in the above pic there is no mod_rewrite loaded module.
Also as a wild hack I even tried rewriting URLs using `.htaccess` file but this is not working. Apache seems to ignore `.htaccess` file although I have put that file inside my root directory.

```
 Note: I am running `PHP` as an apache module
 Using `WAMP` stack
 Using `localhost` as server
```

I need this module badly for URL rewriting purposes. Can you guys suggest some other way to load this module?

**EDIT**

I have tried to rewrite URL from virtual host as the answer suggests that the module is loaded and it does not depend neither on `.htaccess` nor on `info.php`.But stil it is not redirecting. I am adding the `Virtual host` setup below---

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory "/Apache24/htdocs">
Options FollowSymLinks 
AllowOverride All
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</Directory>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "/Apache24/htdocs"
ErrorLog "/Apache24/logs/error.log"
CustomLog "/Apache24/logs/access.log" combined
<directory "/Apache24/htdocs">

    <IfModule rewrite_module>
            Options +FollowSymlinks
            RewriteEngine On
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule rewrite_module>
            RewriteRule   ^working.php   fun.html
    </IfModule>

</directory>
# Rewrite Rules #####################
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^working.php   fun.html
# end Rewrite Rules #################   
</VirtualHost>
```

The above code does not redirect it to `working.php` when I try to run `fun.html`. It simply says:

> the requested URL /working.php was not found on this server.

Comment: `mod_rewrite` is an Apache module, PHP will know nothing about it and therefore it doesn't show up in `phpinfo()`. PHP modules are a completely separate thing.

Comment: @Tero Kilkanen Yes I understand that but phpinfo shows all other loaded modules under 'loaded modules section' only mod_rewrite is not showing up. Can you please explain why does that happen? Also can you tell me why my mod_rewrite module is not working although apache 'httpd -M' command shows it has loaded. Thanks.

Comment: `phpinfo()` shows all PHP modules that are loaded. Those are separate things than Apache modules. I don't know why the module doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried using mod_rewrite directives directly in your server config (or VitualHost)? In a per-directory context, `FollowSymLinks` (or `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`) also needs to be enabled for mod_rewrite to work. eg. `Options +FollowSymLinks`.

Comment: "as a wild hack I even tried rewriting URLs using .htaccess file but this is not working." - a "wild hack"? Define "not working". If it simply didn't do anything then it's possible that something was wrong with your directives that prevented a match, rather than mod_rewrite not being available. (Or `.htaccess` files are not enabled for this directory?) However, if you got an error (eg. a 500 error) then it's possible that mod_rewrite is not enabled.

Comment: @w3dk: I have tried it running from the virtual host but it is not working.. I have updated my question. explained what I tried to do. Thanks.

Comment: "The above code does not redirect it to working.php when I try to run fun.html." - But the above code would do the complete opposite and it's not strictly a "redirect"? Does `fun.html` exist on the filesystem?

Comment: @w3dk: yes it does exists in the file system.

Comment: And the full URL of your test request is `http://localhost/working.php`?

Comment: yes that's my test url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need .htaccess or AllowOverride for mod_rewrite to work, don't use, since you are the admin of your server, since it will just complicate your life and cause unnecessary overhead to your server.
2. Aside from Loading the module the only directive you need is:

   **RewriteEngine on**

Extra:

3. Consider Redirect/RedirectMatch instead (from mod_alias) for simple redirections, if that's all you need.
4. Consider defining your redirects/rewrites in virtualhost context to avoid future nightmares and loss of hair in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

From your linked screenshots, your Server Root (filesystem path) would seem to be `C:/Apache24`, but you make no reference to `C:` in any of your server config directives? You need to reference the full filesystem path, for example:

```
<Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs">
```

> ```
> RewriteRule   ^working.php   fun.html
> ```

This directive, used directly in the VirtualHost (outside of a `<Directory>` container), will never match. When used in a VirtualHost (or server config) context, mod_rewrite matches the full URL path, which notably *includes* the slash prefix. This is an important difference to when using mod_rewrite is a directory/`.htaccess` context (when the slash prefix is excluded).

Comment: I tried it but still not working.